# How can I counter thrust spam?

Tags: mordhau

Rapiers and spears are pretty common to come up against. When fighting someone who just spams the thrust move over and over, how can I effectively counter them (especially with a slower weapon like a 2H sword)?

I can parry, but by the time I riposte I'm already being stabbed again.

Chambering the thrust doesn't seem to work for the same reason. I just get poked again by the time my chamber hits, or it doesn't seem to hit them at all.

I've seen people suggest that chamber morphing can be effective, but I usually end up getting poked early in the slash animation.

Is it just a matter of keeping them at range?

Answer (score 1):

Thrust attacks covers a small degree of angle compared to slash attacks, which often cover more than the whole screen. In 1v1 scenarios, my guess to countering the spam is to step aside then slash back. Try rotating the character to make the slash land earlier to stop their spam.

If you are playing in Frontline mode, another suggestion is to man up with other players, try sticking in a team as thrust attacks can't hit multiple targets standing to the left/right of the original (unlike slash). If the team is cooperative enough, one/some can parry the trusts (or even shield block) while others attack to interrupt them (use thrust to avoid slashing through teammates).